# Is there a way to edit a Google spreadsheet row in a form style view?

Tags: forms, google-sheets

Some of my google docs spreadsheets have become a very wide and scrolling horizontally a long way makes it hard to be sure that you are on the right row.

Is there a way to bring up form linked to the current row to make editing easier, similar to a form in Microsoft Access or Excel and other database programs?

It will be good to be able to scroll back and forth among the rows.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think so. You would need to create a web page and use the google spreadsheet API.